# How to get boundaries of city?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, google-maps-api, arcgis-platform

is there any api to get bounds of city. What i want is i give city name and in return i get that city boundaries.

I have searched google maps, arcgis and OpenStreetMap but didnt found any satisfactory response. I have also used openstreetmaps api but no luck.

Comment: Can you be more specific please.  Do you already have some data from which you want to attempt deriving a city boundary or is this really a question along the lines of "Can anybody tell me where to find the data?".  In answering both these questions, it would be helpful if you told us where in the world you want the data for.  When you say you had no luck with ArcGIS, what do you mean?  Do you mean ESRI's data or the software package?

Comment: nominatim example Birmingham UK http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=birmingham,uk&format=xml returns bounding box (city limit)

Comment: @MappaGnosis i will give specific city name and in return i want that city boundaries

Comment: @Mapperz thanks for help i will check boundingbox and will come back to u soon

Comment: @Mapperz it works for cities. Is there any way i get bounding box of countries and provinces?

Answer (score 2):

You can download city boundary data from the US Census TIGER/Line shapefiles web interface (https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2014/main). Use the dropdown and select "Places" - you can download them for an entire state then query the attribute table for the cities you're interested in.